# Setting attributes on a copy of a function affect the original function too. Why?

Tags: r, functional-programming

I am observing a strange and totally unexpected behaviour when setting attributes to a copy of a function: the attribute is also (implicitely!) set to the copied function.

- What is the explanation for this behaviour ?
- Is it useful (i.e. are there examples of standard packages that leverage this behaviour) ?

Example:

```
v <- is.integer
attr(v, "foo") <- "bar"
attr(is.integer, "foo")
#> "bar" <------------------------- WHY ?
```

Note that this behavior doesn't happen in the following cases:

```
v <- function(...)is.integer(...)
attr(v, "hello") <- "world"
attr(is.integer, "hello")
#> NULL

w <- 1:3
v <- w
attr(v, "foo") <- "bar"
attr(w, "foo")
#> NULL
```

Comment: I get bar instead of foo here. seems to happen only with primitive functions, ie, try with `matrix` or something and it will work as you expect

Comment: indeed it should be bar, and thanks for the tip about primitive functions..it brings me a step further..